# VB6 program on Windows 8.1 fails to print Hebrew with Printer.Print

Tags: encoding, printing, vb6, windows-8.1

I have an old program written in VB6.
I am trying to get it work right on Windows 8.1.

Everything works, except sending text in Hebrew to the printer.
The printer prints "???" instead of Hebrew characters.
It is obvious that this is an encoding problem, but I don't find a way to solve it.
The program works on Windows 7 without any problem!

the relevant code:

```
Printer.Font.Charset = 177 'Hebrew encoding
Printer.Print "<text in Hebrew>"
Printer.EndDoc
```

If someone has an advice, I will appreciate it a lot.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It usualy means the font used does not have those characters. Arial has stuff like גּוּלּ֧֧֧֯.

```
object.FontName [= font]
```

The FontName property syntax has these parts:

Part Description

object An object expression that evaluates to an object in the Applies To list.

font A string expression specifying the font name to use.

Remarks

The default for this property is determined by the system. Fonts available with Visual Basic vary depending on your system configuration, display devices, and printing devices. Font-related properties can be set only to values for which fonts exist.

In general, you should change FontName before setting size and style attributes with the FontSize, FontBold, FontItalic, FontStrikethru, and FontUnderline properties.

Comment: That's not it, missing glyphs are rendered as rectangles.  Question marks are encoding problems.

Comment: I checked the font that is being used, and it has Hebrew characters. If I use this font in Word for example it works well.
It seems like problem in Windows 8.1 and the API that VB6 uses... maybe I should ask Microsoft about it? I don't know where to do so.
Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to set the `Language for non-Unicode programs` to Hebrew. In Win 8 you do it like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/497857/how-to-change-language-for-non-unicode-programs-in-windows-8).

Comment: This option is already set correctly, so this is not the problem. Thanks.